# Display bar graphs using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4

I wrote a code to show data from DB in a table view. How can I show same data in Bar graph instead?

This my action method (Updated):

```
public ActionResult DataFromDataBase()
        {
            var mostRecentMonday = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7).StartOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Monday);
            var weekEnd = mostRecentMonday.AddDays(7).AddSeconds(-1); //will return the end of the day on Sunday

            ViewBag.Monday = mostRecentMonday;
            ViewBag.lastWeekSunday = weekEnd;
            try
            {
                Formatting _jsonSetting = default;
                ViewBag.DataPoints = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(db.Chats.Where(x => System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.MSTChatCreatedDateTime) >= mostRecentMonday
                           && System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.MSTChatCreatedDateTime) <= weekEnd).GroupBy(a => System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(a.MSTChatCreatedDateTime)).Select(b => new ReportVM()
                           {
                               CreatdDate = b.Key,
                               ChatCountCreatdDate = b.Count()

                           }).ToList(), _jsonSetting);

                return View();
            }
            catch (System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException)
            {
                return View("Error");
            }
            catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException)
            {
                return View("Error");
            }
        }
```

View to display Graphs

```
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>

<div id="chartContainer"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var result = @Html.Raw(ViewBag.DataPoints);
    var dataPoints =[];
    for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
        dataPoints.push({label:result[i].x, y:result[i].y});
    }

    $(function () {
        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
            theme: "light2",
            zoomEnabled: true,
            animationEnabled: true,
            title: {
                text: "Line Chart with Data-Points from DataBase"
            },
            data: [
            {
                type: "column",

                dataPoints: dataPoints,
            }
            ]
        });
        chart.render();
    });
</script>
```

No successs. Used js library to display Graphs, but nothing is working for me. Can some one please help?

Comment: what chart plugin are you using?

Comment: @Vidiya Prasanth thank you for your response. For me, this is new, hence unaware of how to begin with the graph.

Comment: try https://www.chartjs.org/ . It is open source and easy to use

Comment: see the above-updated code. Still no success

Answer (score 0):

Go through below link to explore bar chart on chartjs, its free and easy to use charts,

you just have to specify proper data objects
Check below Example

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html

Comment: see the above updated code. Still no success